# All characters in a string must match regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm sorry if this has been up before but I can't find anythin on google that gives what I want.

I've a field where you can write expressions: `x>1`, `x>2||x<1` `(x>1) && (x<2)` etc.
What I want is a regex that checks the expression so it only can contain a certain valid characters to defend against code injection. `a.1` should not match.

So far I'm using this:

```
expression.match('[xX<>=|0-9&().]')
```

But this also returns anything that contains any of these characters. What I want is a expression that only returns if all character match any of thoose in the regex.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need `*` or `+` quantifier after your character class and anchors:

```
/^[xX<>=|0-9&()\s.]*$/.test(expression)
 ^                 ^^
```

Now, it will match

- `^` - start of string
- `[xX<>=|0-9&\s().]*` - *zero or more* (if you use `+`, one or more) of the chars defined in the char class
- `$` - end of string.

Short demo:

```js
console.log(/^[xX<>=|0-9&\s().]*$/.test("a.1"));
console.log(/^[xX<>=|0-9&\s().]*$/.test("(x>1) && (x<2)"));
```

Note I added `\s` to match whitespaces, too.

Comment: Since the `(x>1) && (x<2)` contains spaces, I also suggest adding `\s` into the pattern.

Comment: I tried `new RegExp('/^[xX<>=|0-9&().]*$/').test(expression)` where expression = `x>1` and it gave me false

Comment: Of course it will give you false since your `x>1` does not contain `/` before the beginning and `/` after the end of string. Do not use a RegExp constructor, use a **regex literal**: `/^[xX<>=|0-9&\s().]*$/.test("x>1")`

Comment: Oh so if you don't use a RegExp constructor you've to add / at the start and end to tell the compiler its an regex? Why use that instead of the constructor?

Comment: See [MDN `RegExp` help](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions): *Regular expression literals provide compilation of the regular expression when the script is loaded. When the regular expression will remain constant, use this for better performance... Using the [`RegExp`] constructor function provides runtime compilation of the regular expression. Use the constructor function when you know the regular expression pattern will be changing, or you don't know the pattern and are getting it from another source, such as user input.*

Comment: Ok thank you very much, will mark your answer as correct in 5min.

Comment: Took me half my workday before I found this thread and fixed my issue.  Wish I could give this answer two upvotes.